# If (Variable == Variable + 5)

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to show a certain medal in my scene depending on what your high score is based on the goal of the level.

```
// Get Medal Colour
    if levelHighscore < goalScore {
        scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "noMedal")
    } else if levelHighscore == goalScore {
        scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bronzeMedal")
    } else if levelHighscore > goalScore {
        scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "silverMedal")
    }
```

At the moment i get the high score and compare it to the goal
- if it is less than the goal show noMedal image. If it equals the goal show a bronzeMedal, If the high score is 5 more than the goal show silverMedal and if the high score is 10 higher than the goal show a goldMedal.

Been on this for a while trying all different bits and bobs and for some reason it works in the setup above but when i write

```
    // Get Medal Colour
    if levelHighscore == goalScore+5 {
        scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "silverMedal")
    }
```

it shows nothing.

Comment: Perhaps you want `>=` instead of `==`

Comment: You need to use `if` and `if else` to capture ranges instead of specific values.

Comment: A switch would probably be preferable with this. It's possible now, but will be much nicer in Swift 4: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ From what I understand in this case a one-sided range would essentially end at either `Int.min` or `Int.max` depending on the defined side of the range. It would save a bit of code but won’t be that radical since you could simply explicitly define the missing side as `Int.min` or `Int.max` like I do in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293842/887210)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your comparisons to be like this:

```
if levelHighscore < goalScore {
    scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "noMedal")
} else if levelHighscore >= goalScore + 10 {
    scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "goldMedal")
} else if levelHighscore >= goalScore + 5 {
    scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "silverMedal")
} else {
    scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bronzeMedal")
}
```

The important part is to check for the higher values first, then the lower values.

To make the logic clearer, you can format the code as follows:

```
if levelHighscore < goalScore {
    scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "noMedal")
} else {
    // We now know the score is greater or equal to goal
    // First see if it's hight enough for gold
    if levelHighscore >= goalScore + 10 {
        scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "goldMedal")
    } else {
        // Nope, maybe it's silver
        if levelHighscore >= goalScore + 5 {
            // Yes, it's 5 or more but less than 10 over so it's silver
            scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "silverMedal")
        } else {
            // No, it's less than 5 over leaving bronze
            scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bronzeMedal")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the pyramid of doom that's developing here, I would recommend at least using a guard for the error (noMedal) case.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I don't recommend the "pyramid of doom". That's just for illustration purposes. And why a `guard`? Checking for an insufficient score is just another check in the `if/else`.

Comment: A one line `if` and a long `else` is generally a good candidate for `guard`. It makes it clear what the escape case is and lessens the indentation making it cleaner and readable

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ But my actual answer (the first block of code) does not have a long else nor more than one level of indentation.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your taste, I find this a bit easier to read and understand.

```
switch levelHighscore - goalScore {
case 0 ..< 5:     scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bronzeMedal")
case 5 ..< 10:    scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "silverMedal")
case 10 ... .max: scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "goldMedal")
default:          scoreMedal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "noMedal")
}
```

However, @rmaddy's answer is excellent.

Comment: I like this. Much cleaner. I've spent 35 years programming C/C++/Java/Objective-C. I've spent 6 months in Swift. I need to keep reminding myself of things like the much more powerful and flexible Swift `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There’s some great answers here but I’d choose to do it a little differently.

First of all, a series of concrete values lends itself to using an `enum`:

```
/// Raw values are the minimum for each Medal type.
/// For .none the raw value indicates any negative value
enum Medal: Int {
  case none   = -1
  case bronze = 0
  case silver = 5
  case gold   = 10
}
```

Then we add an initializer that takes a score and a goal. We also add an `image` property that returns an `SKSpriteNode`:

```
extension Medal {
  init(score: Int, goal: Int) {
    switch score - goal {
    case Medal.bronze.rawValue ..< Medal.silver.rawValue: self = .bronze
    case Medal.silver.rawValue ..< Medal.gold.rawValue  : self = .silver
    case Medal.gold.rawValue   ..< Int.max              : self = .gold
    default                                             : self = .none
    }
  }

  var image: SKSpriteNode {
    switch self {
    case .none  : return SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "noMedal")
    case .bronze: return SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bronzeMedal")
    case .silver: return SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "silverMedal")
    case .gold  : return SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "goldMedal")
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can simply do this to get the image:

```
let image = Medal(score: 14, goal: 10).image
```

or

```
let image = Medal.bronze.image
```